# Vue.js leave animation not working as expected

Tags: html, css, vue.js

The [demo](https://jsbin.com/gefoluviqu/edit?html,css,js,output) is quite simple, and similar to the example in the Vue.js docs.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 5s;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.fade-enter-to {
  background: black
}

.fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
  background: red
}

.fade-leave-to {
  background: black;
  width: 1000px;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

The question is, when the leave animation begins, it seems it's removed from the DOM (`v-if` is `false`) so quickly that there isn't any animation at all!

But, if I remove `opacity`, the animation works! **Why does `opacity` matter**?

```css
.fade-leave {
  /* opacity: 0; */
  background: red;
} 

.fade-leave-to {
  background: black;
  width: 1000px;
  /* opacity:1; */
}
```

---

There is another question, I thought the leave animation should be that the DOM background becomes red firstly (while the result is it didn't or I just can't tell), then change to black slowly. So, is it my misconception？

Comment: You should make a function instead of show = !show. The function should start the animation and set a timeout for the show = !show

Answer (score 0):

The opacity is important because the animation is fading according to it.

Here I have added to opacity of 0 directly to the class fade-enter-active of the button Hello. You can see the animation fading step by step.

[image]

Instead, with an opacity of 1, there is no direction to your fading. It stays at 1.

Comment: My question is about leave animation